# Why doesn't ASP.net GridView update MS ACCESS record?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have:

```
<asp:GridView ID="ClassesGridView" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="CourseNumber" DataSourceID="AccessClasses" 
                AutoGenerateEditButton="True" >
                <Columns>
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="CourseNumber" HeaderText="CourseNumber" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="CourseNumber" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="Teacher1" HeaderText="Teacher1" SortExpression="Teacher1" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="T1PhoneNumber" HeaderText="T1PhoneNumber" SortExpression="T1PhoneNumber" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="T1Email" HeaderText="T1Email" SortExpression="T1Email" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="Teacher2" HeaderText="Teacher2" SortExpression="Teacher2" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="T2PhoneNumber" HeaderText="T2PhoneNumber" SortExpression="T2PhoneNumber" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="T2Email" HeaderText="T2Email" SortExpression="T2Email" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="OrderToVisit" HeaderText="OrderToVisit" SortExpression="OrderToVisit" />
                </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
<asp:AccessDataSource ID="AccessClasses" runat="server" DataFile="~/App_Data/SundaySchool.mdb" 
                SelectCommand="SELECT [CourseNumber], [Teacher1], [T1PhoneNumber], [T1Email], [Teacher2], [T2PhoneNumber], [T2Email], [OrderToVisit] FROM [Classes]"
                UpdateCommand="UPDATE Classes SET Teacher1 = @Teacher1 WHERE CourseNumber = @CourseNumber">
</asp:AccessDataSource>
```

For the life of me I can't figure out why this won't update.  The 'Edit' record works, but after changing the record and hitting 'Update' nothing happens.  Everything reverts back.

EDIT:
Something weird is happening here.  If I set a value in the 'Teacher2' column, that will then populate to the 'Teacher1' column.  The CourseNumber column also isn't what it should be which is why WHERE CourseNumber = @CourseNumber is not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured this out.  The UpdateCommand MUST follow the SelectCommand exactly with exception to the Primary Key, CourseNumber.  EVERYTHING in the select must be in the update in the correct.  Once I did that,  everything worked great!!

Answer (score 1):

You have to change the UpdateCommand, notice `?` instead of `@`:

```
<asp:AccessDataSource ID="AccessClasses" runat="server" DataFile="~/App_Data/SundaySchool.mdb" 
                SelectCommand="SELECT [CourseNumber], [Teacher1], [T1PhoneNumber], [T1Email], [Teacher2], [T2PhoneNumber], [T2Email], [OrderToVisit] FROM [Classes]"
                UpdateCommand="UPDATE Classes SET Teacher1 = ? WHERE CourseNumber = @CourseNumber">
</asp:AccessDataSource>
```

Here's more info about AccessDataSource: [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.accessdatasource%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).

Comment: Still doesn't work... Doesn't make any sense.  I have 5 other grid views that update just fine.  This is the only one that has a problem.